# How can I get the description of the table fields in my database using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

How get this: data type, length, if null, primary key of the columns in the table

```
Users id primary key
email varchar(100) not null
active Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't offer any support for this - you will need to use regular, raw SQL statements to query the SQL Server **system catalog views** :

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    c.is_nullable,
    TypeName = ty.name,
    c.max_length,
    PKName = i.name,
    PKColumn = pkc.name
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND i.is_primary_key = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.index_id = i.index_id AND ic.object_id = t.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.columns pkc ON pkc.column_id = ic.column_id AND pkc.object_id = i.object_id
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta para ejecutar este tipo de comando, would I have to use?
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand ()

Comment: @iverGonzalezvidal: either that, yes, or use a "classic" ADO.NET connection with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to handle this

Comment: I am very grateful